# Authentication issues with the Twitter API

Tags: php, curl, twitter, twitter-oauth

I'm trying to display the latest tweets of a Twitter account on my website, and I'm trying to fetch the data using cURL and PHP. When I use the OAuth tool (signature generator) on the Twitter Developers website. There is a cURL command that is generated and it runs just fine on my terminal. However, when I try to use cURL with the same parameters in my PHP code, I get the following error :

```
{
   "errors": [
       {
           "code": 215,
           "message": "Bad Authentication data."
       }
   ]
}
```

Here is the cURL command :

```
 curl --get 'https://api.twitter.com/1.1/statuses/user_timeline.json' --data 'count=2&screen_name=[my user name]' --header 'Authorization: OAuth oauth_consumer_key="[my key]", oauth_nonce="[my key]", oauth_signature="[the signature]", oauth_signature_method="HMAC-SHA1", oauth_timestamp="1439736924", oauth_version="1.0"' --verbose
```

And here is my PHP code :

```
$ch = curl_init("https://api.twitter.com/1.1/statuses/user_timeline.json?count=2&screen_name=XXXXX");

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
    'Authorization' => 'OAuth',
    'oauth_consumer_key' => '[my key]',
    'oauth_nonce' => '[my key]',
    'oauth_signature' => '[the signature]',
    'oauth_signature_method' => 'HMAC-SHA1',
    'oauth_timestamp' => '1439736924',
    'oauth_version' => '1.0')
);

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, array(
    'count' => 2,
    'screen_name' => '[my username]')
);

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);

echo curl_exec($ch);
```

The values are exactly the same and I don't understand why it works with the *curl* command but not in the PHP code. Here are the two logs :

cURL command (works fine):

```
* Connected to api.twitter.com (199.16.156.199) port 443 (#0)
* successfully set certificate verify locations:
*   CAfile: none
  CApath: /etc/ssl/certs/
* TLSv1.2, TLS handshake, Client hello (1):
* TLSv1.2, TLS handshake, Server hello (2):
* TLSv1.2, TLS handshake, CERT (11):
* TLSv1.2, TLS handshake, Server key exchange (12):
* TLSv1.2, TLS handshake, Server finished (14):
* TLSv1.2, TLS handshake, Client key exchange (16):
* TLSv1.2, TLS change cipher, Client hello (1):
* TLSv1.2, TLS handshake, Finished (20):
* TLSv1.2, TLS change cipher, Client hello (1):
* TLSv1.2, TLS handshake, Finished (20):
* SSL connection using TLSv1.2 / ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256
* Server certificate:
*    subject: C=US; ST=California; L=San Francisco; O=Twitter, Inc.; OU=Twitter Security; CN=api.twitter.com
*    start date: 2014-08-03 00:00:00 GMT
*    expire date: 2016-12-31 23:59:59 GMT
*    subjectAltName: api.twitter.com matched
*    issuer: C=US; O=VeriSign, Inc.; OU=VeriSign Trust Network; OU=Terms of use at https://www.verisign.com/rpa (c)10; CN=VeriSign Class 3 Secure Server CA - G3
*    SSL certificate verify ok.
> GET /1.1/statuses/user_timeline.json?count=2&screen_name=XXX HTTP/1.1
> User-Agent: curl/7.38.0
> Host: api.twitter.com
> Accept: */*
> Authorization: OAuth oauth_consumer_key="BBBBBB",     oauth_nonce="CCCCCCCC", oauth_signature="DDDDDDDD", oauth_signature_method="HMAC-SHA1", oauth_timestamp="1439736924", oauth_version="1.0"
> 
< HTTP/1.1 200 OK
< cache-control: no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate, pre-check=0, post-check=0
< content-disposition: attachment; filename=json.json
< content-length: 7512
< content-type: application/json;charset=utf-8
< date: Sun, 16 Aug 2015 16:09:46 GMT
< expires: Tue, 31 Mar 1981 05:00:00 GMT
< last-modified: Sun, 16 Aug 2015 16:09:46 GMT
< pragma: no-cache
< server: tsa_b
< set-cookie: guest_id=v1%3A143974138658672554; Domain=.twitter.com; Path=/; Expires=Tue, 15-Aug-2017 16:09:46 UTC
< status: 200 OK
< strict-transport-security: max-age=631138519
< x-connection-hash: ae1b9fcc59bb90b767b246dfd06f6c94
< x-content-type-options: nosniff
< x-frame-options: SAMEORIGIN
< x-rate-limit-limit: 300
< x-rate-limit-remaining: 298
< x-rate-limit-reset: 1439741812
< x-response-time: 23
< x-transaction: 8515dfd151751885
< x-twitter-response-tags: BouncerCompliant
< x-xss-protection: 1; mode=block
<
```

PHP log (returns the error message):

```
* Hostname in DNS cache was stale, zapped
*   Trying 199.16.156.199...
* Connected to api.twitter.com (199.16.156.199) port 443 (#0)
* successfully set certificate verify locations:
*   CAfile: none
  CApath: /etc/ssl/certs/
* SSL connection using TLSv1.2 / ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256
* Server certificate:
*    subject: C=US; ST=California; L=San Francisco; O=Twitter, Inc.; OU=Twitter Security; CN=api.twitter.com
*    start date: 2014-08-03 00:00:00 GMT
*    expire date: 2016-12-31 23:59:59 GMT
*    subjectAltName: api.twitter.com matched
*    issuer: C=US; O=VeriSign, Inc.; OU=VeriSign Trust Network; OU=Terms of use at https://www.verisign.com/rpa (c)10; CN=VeriSign Class 3 Secure Server CA - G3
*    SSL certificate verify ok.
> GET /1.1/statuses/user_timeline.json?count=2&screen_name=XXXX HTTP/1.1
Host: api.twitter.com
Accept: */*
Authorization: OAuth
oauth_consumer_key: BBBBBB
oauth_nonce: CCCCCCC
oauth_signature: DDDDDDD
oauth_signature_method: HMAC-SHA1
oauth_timestamp: 1439740787
oauth_version: 1.0

< HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request
< content-length: 62
< content-type: application/json; charset=utf-8
< date: Sun, 16 Aug 2015 16:26:50 GMT
< server: tsa_b
< set-cookie: guest_id=v1%3A143974241022741403; Domain=.twitter.com; Path=/; Expires=Tue, 15-Aug-2017 16:26:50 UTC
< strict-transport-security: max-age=631138519
< x-connection-hash: abbabb47dc8a7d355f595f389f868de2
< x-response-time: 4
< 
* Connection #0 to host api.twitter.com left intact
```

Any help would be appreciated. If possible, I really would like to use cURL instead of a third party library.

Thanks

EDIT : Michael's solution didn't work, but here is the updated PHP output :

```
 Authorization: OAuth oauth_consumer_key="...", oauth_nonce="...", oauth_signature="...", oauth_signature_method="HMAC-SHA1" oauth_timestamp= "1439744503", oauth_version= "1.0"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The chief difference between these is that in the CLI `curl` command, the `Authorization` header is specified as a *single string* with multiple `key=value` pairs separated by commas.  But in your PHP code you have specified those `key=value` pairs as *multiple individual headers*.  You just need to add a single `Authorization` header with all of those values concatenated into one string.

The CLI request's header output:

```
Authorization: OAuth oauth_consumer_key="BBBBBB",     oauth_nonce="CCCCCCCC", oauth_signature="DDDDDDDD", oauth_signature_method="HMAC-SHA1", oauth_timestamp="1439736924", oauth_version="1.0"
```

The PHP request's header output differs:

```
Authorization: OAuth
oauth_consumer_key: BBBBBB
oauth_nonce: CCCCCCC
oauth_signature: DDDDDDD
oauth_signature_method: HMAC-SHA1
oauth_timestamp: 1439740787
oauth_version: 1.0
```

So the correct PHP to produce a comparable single-header string would be:

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
// All OAuth values in a single Authorization header string.
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
    'Authorization' => 'OAuth oauth_consumer_key="[my key]", oauth_nonce="[my key]", oauth_signature="[the signature]", oauth_signature_method="HMAC-SHA1", oauth_timestamp="1439736924", oauth_version="1.0"'
  )
);
// etc... Everything else should be fine as you have it
```

Comment: @user1319182 `oauth_timestamp= "1439744503", oauth_version= "1.0"` I see extra spaces after the `=`. Make sure your PHP doesn't have those.

Comment: @user1319182 Also, I just edited out the OAuth tokens etc from your edit above. I can't remove them from the edit history though. You should probably request a new token.

Comment: Will do. Thanks again !